# how to insert data from angular2 to elasticsearch

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, angular2-forms, angular2-services

This is my registration form, I want to store this data to elastic search. I'm new to elastic search and angular 2 any example would help.

```
            <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="register" class="animate form">
    <form  action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 
        <h1> Sign up </h1> 
        <p> 
            <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
            <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
            <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/> 
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
            <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
            <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
        </p>
        <p class="signin button"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/> 
        </p>
        <p class="change_link">  
            Already a member ?
            <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to send this data to your database ? simply send `form.value`

Comment: using angular2 i want to store data to elasticsearch http://stackoverflow.com/users/5043867/pardeep-jain

Comment: using angular2 you can save data of the form by simply applying `form_name.value` by doing so you will get form data

Comment: Please, remove the tags that belong to a different form at the top. They are not related to the question, right?